# Android Oreo battery optimization causes delays in FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

I have implemented the FCM exactly like documentation of if says:

I have a service like this 
`public class TCMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService`

And I have declared it in manifest like so:

```
<service android:name=".services.TCMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I target and compile with SDK level 25, and my firebase version is 10.2.1.

Now the problem is that on Android 8.0 sometimes I have huge delays when I receive push notifications. it can come after a few minutes. But this is not always so, sometimes things work just like expected, push notifications came very quickly.

I tried to update the FCM version to the last one but that did not help.

But when in the settings I turn off the battery optimization for my app everything works fine. But this is not a solution. 
What can I do to make FCM work as expected on Android 8.0?

Comment: have you tested it in doze mode or with default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found the solution.

In order to fix delays on Android 8 push notifications you need to set the minimum `compileSdkVersion 25` and

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

in project level gradle file.

This fixes the issue, hope it can help someone

Comment: @Fakher are you sure that compile version of the SDK is 25 ? and buildToolsVersion and targetSdkVersion everything is pointing on 25 ?

Answer (score 2):

Only high-priority messages are handled right away, when the device is in [doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html). So make sure your FCM message is sent with priority "high".

See [the documentation for Firebase messaging here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message), and the [documentation for doze and FCM here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#using_fcm).

Comment: By default, priority is HIGH, but it doesn't work for me on Android Oreo

Answer (score 1):

You must:

- Update compile version to 26
- Update Build tools to 26.0.2
- Minimum google service version : 11.0.4
- Add this dependency:

  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'
- Update firebase plugin to:

  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
- Add google repository in your project gradle

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()
      }
  }
- In your java cod the notification manager is created in another way
  in Android O:

  ```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           String id = "id_product";
           // The user-visible name of the channel.
           CharSequence name = "Product";
           // The user-visible description of the channel.
           String description = "Notifications regarding our products";
           int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX;
           NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
           // Configure the notification channel.
           mChannel.setDescription(description);
           mChannel.enableLights(true);
           // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
           // channel, if the device supports this feature.
           mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
           notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
  ```

You can find the full code in this [link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging).